# How do I move only 2 elements of navbar to the right?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I would like to move only the logout and {{user.first.name}} to the right. I tried using ms-auto but it didn't work. Am I using it correctly?

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'navbar/css/style.css' %}">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Website Monitoring Portal</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'add-url' %}">Add URL</a>
          </li>
          
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}


          
          <li class="nav-item ms-auto ">
            <a class="nav-link" href = "{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
          </li>
          <h5 class="li-right" >
          <li class="nav-item"> Hello, {{user.first_name}} </li>
          </h5>

          {% else %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href = "{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
          </li>
          <li >
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
          </li>
          {% endif %}
          
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex" role="search" method="POST" action="{% url 'search-url' %}" >
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search Url" aria-label="Search" name="searched">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  </html>
```

The Home and Add URL will remain on the left while Logout and 'hello' should be on the right. I tried using CSS and using text-align: right but that did not work also. So now I tried ms auto but it is still not working. Some guidance on this will be really helpful. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

`text-align:right` only aligns the text inside of the object. it does not move the object itself.

I would be able to help more if you could also share your css and add a code snipplet.

Did you try using `float:right`? like so:

```
<li class="nav-item right-nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href = "{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
</li>
```

```
.right-nav-item{
    float:right;
}
```